# Sorting and storing number in hashmap

Tags: java, java-8

I need your help in the below scenario.

I would be having any number from 1 to 100000 in a list. I need to split those numbers it into 10 groups. Numbers from 1 - 10000 should lie into group 1 in hashmap .. similarly for remaining groups.

My final Map should be like this

```
Key 1= 1-10000 Value 8990
Key 2 = 10001-20000 value 12000
....
Key 10 = 90000-100000 value 95001
```

It can be done via if loop to check for every 10000 and store it in corresponding key. But do we have any other way to do it? Any util function which already does it?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Why does one group start at `10001`, but another at `90000`? Can you name a consistent rule for those groups?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stream API function [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) to convert the list/stream of `int` values to a `Map<>` you want. In this case you use the [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) collector and specify `(i-1)/10000+1` as the key. This way the values will put in lists based on the remainder of `i` divided by 10000. The code might look like this:

```
List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000,
    10001, 20000, 8990, 12000, 95001,
    90000, 90001, 100000);
    
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> mapping = values
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> (i-1)/10000+1));
System.out.println(mapping);
```

This will generate the following output:

```
{1=[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 8990],
 2=[10001, 20000, 12000],
 9=[90000],
 10=[95001, 90001, 100000]}
```